# Memory card does not mount

Tags: mount, 13.04

I upgraded my OS from 12.10 to 13.04 and i am not able to mount my memory card.

Snap shot of the error.

[image]

I used to see EOS_DIGITal which is the name of memory card before clicking OK

After i click OK i cannot see the same any more. Snap shot attached. below

[image]

I edited /etc/modules and added this **tifm_sd** to the end of file. After rebooting i could see EOS_DIGITAL. I tried to open and a pop up with error displayed as in first snapshot.

I do not know how to overcome the error and access my memory card inserted to my laptop.
Edit:

```
 raghu@raghu-vaio:~$  sudo fdisk -l
```

[sudo] password for raghu:

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdab78852

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1            2048    26331135    13164544   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
  /dev/sda2   *    26331136    26535935      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3        26535936   441143295   207303680    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda4       441145342  1465145082   511999870+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       441145344   835999743   197427200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda6       836001792  1045714943   104856576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda7      1045716992  1255430143   104856576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda8      1255432192  1465145082   104856445+  83  Linux
```

Comment: It says 'can't read superblock'. Maybe filesystem on your memory card is corrupted?

To give us more info, please run `sudo fdisk -l` with your memory card inserted and paste output to your question. This command outputs info about all disks connected to your PC and their partitions.

Comment: @user31389 added the output of the command asked. The memory card is 2gb.

Comment: can you format this device under linux?

Comment: i can't even mount. so how can i format the same. I can't see it under media/raghu. If i mount other partitions i can see the same under media/raghu. The card is not corrupted i am able to use the same in my camera (cannon 600D)

Comment: It looks like your memory card isn't detected as a valid device or something. Maybe it's broken? Does it work on other computers? Or in Windows? If it doesn't work anywhere, it's broken. If it works somewhere else... I have no idea what to do.

Comment: absolutely works on windows. even works on camera